# Using php class methods inside Twig template

Tags: php, twig, slim

In my user class I have a multidimensional array containing rights this user is allowed. Depending on these rights certain content should become viewable within the Twig template, such as a link to visit the Admin section of the site. In order to check if a user has the necessary rights I have a class method `$user->hasRights( $right )` which should return true if that right is contained within the $user->_rights array.

My problem is how do I call that class method from with the Twig template? This gives me an exception error.

```
{% if user.hasRights('admin') %}
   <!-- admin link here -->
{% endif %)
```

Sample of $user->_rights:

```
$user->_rights = array(
    array( 'id' => 1, 'name' => 'admin' ),
    array( 'id' => 2, 'name' => 'moderator' )
);
```

There will be many other rights...setting a class property based on the presence of a right isn't exactly feasible.

Comment: What exception? Your code should work.

Comment: Haha, the class method is expecting an array. I put in a check to change it to an array and it worked. Is it possible to pass an array through the Twig method and how would that look?